# Crash on FIRApp.configure() method

Tags: ios, firebase

I added a firebase framework using cocoapods to existing Project but a crash occurs at the `FIRApp.configure()` method.

To figure out the problem, I create a new project and add a firebase Framework which is working.

I don't know what could be the Problem.

Comment: What's written in the console? Did you add the Firebase configuration file? You need to add more details

Comment: Having the same issue today... Nothing in the console. Plist file is still there... Any Idea?

Comment: This happens when another analytics (like AppDynamics) has conflicting 'method swizzle'.

Answer (score 2):

[Make sure GoogleService-Info.plist is in your build target](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/5#issuecomment-333264355).